# How to parse json object and array together using volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

This is my json object and array:

```
 {
    "states": [
        {
            "physical_state": "QLD",
            "_count": "333",
            "state": "Queensland"
        },
        {
            "physical_state": "VIC",
            "_count": "247",
            "state": "Victoria"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to parse this json using volley?

Answer (score 0):

> How to parse this json using volley ??

[Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster. Instead of parsing JSON and XML.

Use [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) or [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for parsing JSON string